# QueryBuilder with a relationship in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, relationship, query-builder

I'm coding in Symfony a search bar working with a query builder for an entity named "Structure" which is related to an entity "Partenaire" (OneToMany), it's working great but the problem is that it shows all the structures and I need to display only the structures related to the Partenaire. If someone can help me to solve this issue, thank you.

PartenaireController.php:

```
#[Route('/{id}', name: 'app_partenaire_show', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function show(Partenaire $partenaire, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, PartenaireRepository $partenaireRepository,Request $request, PartenairePermissionRepository $partenairePermissionRepository, StructureRepository $structureRepository): Response
{
    $getEmail = $this->getUser()->getEmail();
    $partenaireId = $entityManager->getRepository(Partenaire::class)->findOneBy([
        'id' => $request->get('id')
    ]);

    $search2 = $structureRepository->findOneBySomeField2(
        $request->query->get('q')
    );
    
    return $this->render('partenaire/show.html.twig', [
        'partenaire' => $partenaire,
        'permission'=>$partenairePermissionRepository->findBy(
            ['partenaire' => $partenaireId],
        ),
      'structures'=>$search2, // show all the structures

      /*  'structures'=>$structureRepository->findBy( // show the structure linked to the partenaire but doesn't work with the search
            ['partenaire' => $partenaireId],
            [],
        ),*/
        'email'=>$getEmail,
    ]);
}
```

StructureRepository.php :

```
public function findOneBySomeField2(string $search2 = null): array
{
    $queryBuilder =  $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->orderBy('q.id' , 'ASC');

    if ($search2) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere('q.Adresse LIKE :search')
            ->setParameter('search', '%'.$search2.'%');
    }

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
        ;
}
```

Comment: The arguments for the `find...` function don't match the ones passed in the controller, so this should throw an error. Is this the actual code? It's like if you tried to refactor the controller code "on the fly". There are too many things in here that could be going wrong. Please confirm this is what you are working with or otherwise edit the question to reflect the current code.

Comment: Yes I edited the orginal code, the problem is that it is showing all the "Structures" and not "Structures" that are related to the "Partenaire" and I don't know how to filter that and where, in the query builder or in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to limit your results to the desired `Partenaire` by adding a condition. You can achieve this by simply passing another argument to the repository function.

I've removed the commented code in the controller and the loading of the Partenaire entity, as it *should* be already loaded thanks to the magic of [param converters](https://symfony.com/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/current/annotations/converters.html).

```
#[Route('/{id}', name: 'app_partenaire_show', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
public function show(Partenaire $partenaire, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, Request $request, PartenairePermissionRepository $partenairePermissionRepository, StructureRepository $structureRepository): Response
{
    $getEmail = $this->getUser()->getEmail();
    // The Partenaire should already be loaded

    $result = $structureRepository->findByPartenaireWithFilter(
         $partenaire,
         $request->query->get('q')
    );
    
    return $this->render('partenaire/show.html.twig', [
        'partenaire' => $partenaire,
        'permission' => $partenairePermissionRepository->findBy(
            ['partenaire' => $partenaireId],
        ),
        'structures' => $search2, // show all the structures
        'email' => $getEmail,
    ]);
}
```

As for the repository, it's pretty straightforward: pass the loaded partenaire and add a `where` clause.

```
public function findByPartenaireWithFilter(Partenaire $partenaire, string $search2 = null): array
{
    $queryBuilder =  $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->where('q.partenaire = :partenaire')
        ->setParameter('partenaire', $partenaire)
        ->orderBy('q.id' , 'ASC');

    if (null !== $search2) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere('q.Adresse LIKE :search')
            ->setParameter('search', '%'.$search2.'%');
    }

    return $queryBuilder
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

As for the `permissions` key in the controller, I think what you are trying to do, I'd recommend looking into [security voters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html).

Answer (score 2):

as it's a One To Many relation, you should join the right table and add a where statement in your structure query like  :

```
public function findByPartenaireWithFilter(Partenaire $partenaire, string $search2 = null): array
{
    $queryBuilder =  $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
        ->leftJoin('q.partenaire','p')
        ->where('p.partenaire.id = :partenaireId')
        ->setParameter('partenaireId', $partenaire->getId())
        ->orderBy('q.id' , 'ASC');

    if (null !== $search2) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere('q.Adresse LIKE :search')
            ->setParameter('search', '%'.$search2.'%');
    }

    return $queryBuilder
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to do this and find the entity Partenaire related to the Structure but it always give me a null exception, but is there a way to filter the results directly in the controller ?

Comment: can you update your question with the exact query you made with the null exception ?

Comment: @Epson184 , i edited my answer. I'm not sure that it can be done by passing the whole object. Maybe it's mandatory to join the table and set the id as a parameter.